# TypeScript method that compares string argument with 100 last strings sent to method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, collections

I need to create an method in a class in TypeScript (v2.6.1) running in Node.js (v8.9.1) that takes a string, compares the string sent as argument with the last 100 strings sent to the method. There is no need to keep strings in memory if the application restarts. My idea is something like this:

```
class StringService {

    private last100Strings;    //What type?

    constructor() {
    }

    checkIfIsInLast100Strings(string : string) : boolean {
        //check if string is in the last 100 strings checked
        //if yes 
            //return true
        //if no
            //add the string to last100strings
            //check if the last100strings contains more than 100 strings
            //if yes
                //remove the oldest string
            //return false
    }
}
```

I was first thinking of using set for the .has method but I can't find a way to delete the oldest string from the set of strings. Instead I will go for an implementation using a string array but as the method will be executed frequently I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Any suggestions on how to implement this in an efficient way?

Comment: I don't even remember how TS 2.6 works)))

Comment: @captain-yossarian there is very little to do with TS. It's just a datastructure/algorithm question. I doubt the version of TS will have a huge impact on that.

Comment: For best performance, I would probably use both a Set and an Array.  Then, you can use the Set to quickly see if it was in the last 100 and you can use the Array to know which is the oldest item that you can then remove from the Array and the Set.

Comment: @jfriend00 not sure the array is even needed. The set will keep the items in insertion order, so we can just create a new set with the *last* 100 items. Although, the "last one" might be a bit off, due to the deduplication. Assuming we are OK with the last 100 *unique* strings, then we could just keep the "last item" as a separate variable, rather than an array, then we can `set.delete(last)` and `last = set[Symbol.iterator]().next().value`

Comment: @VLAZ - Clever idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: since this is applicable for *any* amount of strings, I'd use `N` to denote that. In your case `N = 100` but you can trivially change it.

You only need to keep a Set of the items because you only insert unique strings in it. The set preserves the insertion order of the items, so you can get the oldest one by getting the "first" item in the set.

Here is how the implementation can look like:

```typescript
class StringService {
    private maxSize: number;
    private lastNStrings: Set<string> = new Set();

    constructor(maxSize = 100) { //make the max size configurable but default to 100
        if (maxSize <= 0){
            throw new Error("You need a positive value for the size");
        }
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    checkIfIsInLastStrings(string: string): boolean {
        //check if string is in the last N strings checked
        if (this.lastNStrings.has(string)) {//if yes 
            return true
        } else {//if no
            //add the string to lastNStrings
            this.lastNStrings.add(string);

            //check if the lastNStrings contains more than N strings
            if (this.lastNStrings.size > this.maxSize) { //if yes
                //remove the oldest string
                const [oldest] = this.lastNStrings; // equivalent to this.lastNStrings[Symbol.iterator]().next().value
                this.lastNStrings.delete(oldest);
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuAnAlgOwOawKaIG7OC2gG8AoaC6ABxVzHiIFswAPWZALywC5pUBXRgCMcAbnKUayOg2jgI8AHIIUGCL2zwAPAtXoAfNAC8fLAHc4WeAAoAlOIkVgAe1S7+weM8TXmbTkQmAIwADCG2JNAA9FHMANZE8AAWTKzQEAHQLqgAZsjo-IhgQiBEQvzw0AAmWDlg-CCVXtChIY6UFMg50L6s7FzQWibhZB1jlMmIzhao5tAAoohTPgBEAJrO-KZYVdBg1M4Z8NJEdCD8RDne0MlEGVwr9u0dAL7PE0nIEAB0fv2B0D+AXEr1I7WAKWAcQAkjloRBoagADKQeAqNDoCDWXQY3g4jC2XhCZzOUpgVAkd4UGIQrBQ6BddJIDEMmBoG4pOSo6CKJl6GC0qE7KkM7rWZJfb7yJTotTfJKQbHMgkRYgxRkATywMBFHUQVkKFKQFxFL2gWBAECIaqijNQzl1lBiYCqu1ufJZzWlymVmMdFAlP29ssx3xdVSVeie-uiUUFcVFHKIwd9Atc8DAaBgjG8iQVFN5+L943GjPFnyDqJ9-O+9yIhkDvz6AVVsc12pjHRi+pzuDzRFJNQUHownco2WHAG1B9r4ABdYwcyUp-miWPmgCO-GkYFKqCaziXlYU1YxEEnsA1wlJ32QDCKXkQc7s31mLBstm+ZxNJd-R6lVYhj8NSlAw1gzgoTx-pQbzQRQ+rwIa0B1JaWCmu0bxvGCE6VFaeAEACswWCG2D4YQ1gACz2HB1JRFyw4UXw0y8Fo9qzPopATqSWBSs46DYjg+CEN88awvCiIogoQHWCsYCPNRMTIbuVprtK0CMfaZi8LJKyca4EDcbx-F4UJPGiXCCLIqi0krEI8lropKEqfRlQacx0A6QANB5dl6W4hkgHxAlkWZkIwhZEnWamMlybYCl0caRCqdyblaR5cnebZulcaURnBaZIlhWJlmSWi0UrMA9nrk5WDJQxTFpV5PkrJllV+QZuWBcZgkEYVdLheJVlSeVVRVY5ym1S56kNdpGXNa1LUeaN7UBUFJm9eZg2lTZWBjXRNV1a5M3zR5lWZaNmW7StnVrT1wmbSVUX8jJdlxQ5CWIBc0CHdNmnaXZC3nYtKxXTlPFdflG1FRFQ1lc9FV7Tcn1JVNqX-cDZ1LcDoP6at3UhX1ULFZFw3w6Nb3rol32o8dWWA1jl3ZbjN34wVD0k3DZ4ybtFOKVTP1oydCNA4z13g7dBPs7DNk5IjB0039p3AxdHm7ZlstAA)

As far as I am aware, there are no TypeScript syntax since version 2.6 that would impact this. I'm unable to test it with the old version, however. If there are, they should be minor and easy to amend.

Here is a JavaScript demo of the code:

```js
class StringService {
    lastNStrings = new Set();

    constructor(maxSize = 100) { //make the max size configurable but default to 100
        if (maxSize <= 0) {
            throw new Error("You need a positive value for the size");
        }
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    checkIfIsInLastStrings(string) {
        //check if string is in the last N strings checked
        if (this.lastNStrings.has(string)) {//if yes 
            return true
        } else {//if no
            //add the string to lastNStrings
            this.lastNStrings.add(string);

            //check if the lastNStrings contains more than N strings
            if (this.lastNStrings.size > this.maxSize) { //if yes
                //remove the oldest string
                const [oldest] = this.lastNStrings; // equivalent to this.lastNStrings[Symbol.iterator]().next().value
                this.lastNStrings.delete(oldest);
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}


const service = new StringService(4);             // last 4 now: <none>
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("a")); // false; last 4 now: "a"
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("b")); // false; last 4 now: "a", "b"
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("a")); // true ; last 4 now: "a", "b"
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("c")); // false; last 4 now: "a", "b", "c"
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("d")); // false; last 4 now: "a", "b", "c", "d"
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("e")); // false; last 4 now: "b", "c", "d", "e"
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("b")); // true ; last 4 now: "b", "c", "d", "e"
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("c")); // true ; last 4 now: "b", "c", "d", "e"
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("d")); // true ; last 4 now: "b", "c", "d", "e"
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("e")); // true ; last 4 now: "b", "c", "d", "e"
console.log(service.checkIfIsInLastStrings("f")); // false; last 4 now: "c", "d", "e", "f"
```

Comment: thank you! I did a comparison between implementing this using an array and a Set and the Set implementation is 4 times faster.